# Display either one of the dropdown in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am trying to display dropdown based on one uniqueid of the page.
I cannot access that uniqueid in the html so taking the separate id's of each dropdown I am hiding one and showing one dropdown based on the value of uniqueid.

But the problem is the value coming has one comma(,) which is not desired.
Is there any way by which I can access the value of uniqueid in HTML and display the dropdowns ( I dont want to show one and hide another. )

```
<select  id="x" style="margin-top: 20px">
   <c:forEach items="${reporttypes}" var="reporttype">        
           <option value="${reporttype.reportTypeName}">${reporttype.reportTypeName}</option>        
   </c:forEach>
</select>

<select  id="y" style="margin-top: 20px">                             
   <c:forEach items="${reporttypes}" var="reporttype">
       <option value="${reporttype.reportTypeName}">${reporttype.reportTypeName}</option>        
   </c:forEach>                                    
</select>


 if(document.getElementById("abc").value == "TTL"){           
               $('#x').show();
               $('#y').hide();
            } 
            else {
                 $('#x').hide();
               $('#y').show();
              }    
        });
```

now I am trying to do this but it doesnt work

```
 <select name="typeOption" id="typeOptionIdTTL" class="typeOptionClassTTL" style="margin-top: 20px">    
  <script> 
    if(document.getElementById("abc")=="TTL"){
        <c:forEach items="${reporttypes}" var="reporttype">
           <option value="${reporttype.reportTypeName}">${reporttype.reportTypeName}</option>
         </c:forEach>
     }
      </script>
    </select>
```

now instead of calling the script in html. I am calling this function but still not working.

```
function PopulateTypeOption(){     

         <c:forEach items="${reporttypes}" var="reporttype">
            if(document.getElementById("abc")=="TTL"){

                   select.append($('<option></option>').val(${reporttype.reportTypeName}).html(${reporttype.reportTypeName}));
            }
            else{

                     select.append($('<option></option>').val(${reporttype.reportTypeName}).html(${reporttype.reportTypeName}));
                               }
         </c:forEach>
    }
```

Comment: what is in your model? Might also be good to know what the compiled html file looks like.

Comment: just think I have 3 dropdowns and based on the value of 1 I want to display other. but donot want to hide and show. I want to execute the if condition on the jsp page itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a function in javascript which will populate the options at run time.
call that function in document.ready.
for eg.

```
function Populate(){        
         if(document.getElementById("abc").value == "TTL" ){
            <c:forEach items="${reporttypes}" var="reporttype">
                 $("#x").append("<option values =${reporttype.reportTypeName}>${reporttype.reportTypeName}</option>");

             </c:forEach>
         }
         else{
            <c:forEach items="${reporttypes}" var="reporttype">

                   $("#abc").append("<option values =${reporttype.reportTypeName}>${reporttype.reportTypeName}</option>");

            </c:forEach>
         }         
      }
```

you dont need 2 separate ids x and y. only one will suffice now.

Comment: so do i need to call only select in html ?

Comment: yes. just select function and onselect call this function.